# How do I remove [New Lead] from the Live Agent Chat Transcript information?

Tags: community, liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

When a user opens my live agent chat, the Agent receives this Live Agent Chat user information form that contains their webpage/browser information as well as the Contact information. I can't seem to find where to remove the ability to create a New Lead as the business requirement does not need Leads.

I've looked on the Live Agent Chat Transcript Page layouts and cannot find the button to remove here. It seems to be something with the Live Chat Transcript but I cant remove the buttons.

[image: Screenshot of]

Comment: did you tried using javascript to hide that button on the page layout

Comment: no @AvijitChakraborty I am looking for out-of-the-box functionality first before having to rely on development to remove something that seems like it should be toggle-able

Comment: Hi @Geo have you solved the problem? I'm stuck on the same page, I don't know how to remove/edit those actions

Comment: @reshad I don't recall the answer to this but I believe it involved ensuring either the user doesn't have access to lead or, you remove the new lead button from the various page layouts/global actions from the user/profile.